# Правописание слова (не)крошащийся

Tags: орфография

Слитно или раздельно нужно писать слово (не)крошащийся в предложении *Мякиш мягкий, легко сжимаемый, (не)крошащийся*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как прямого противопоставления нет, я думаю, нужно писать слитно: **некрошащийся**.

Если напишем

> Мякиш мягкий, легко сжимаемый, не крошащийся.

читатель может прочесть как "такой, чтобы легко сжимался, а не крошился при сжатии" - то есть воспринять это как подразумеваемое автором противопоставление.

А может быть, можно "играть смыслом" - в зависимости от того, хотим мы или нет придать оттенок противопоставления. Если хотим - раздельно, если же просто хотим сухое перечисление свойств мякиша - слитно.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку здесь описываются свойства мякиша, а не отрицание какого-либо из этих свойств, то логично слитное написание. Раздельное написание не будет орфографической ошибкой, но тогда вся фраза будет иметь довольно странный смысл.

Answer (score 2):

Слитное написание: Мякиш мягкий, легко сжимаемый, некрошащийся.

При отсутствии зависимых слов **причастие по значению приближается к прилагательному** и в данном случае обозначает не признак реального действия, а способность к этому действию, то есть описывает физические свойства материала (наряду с другими однородными прилагательными в составе именного сказуемого).